# Open separate console for standard-stream and error-stream in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, console

I would like to have 2 console windows in Eclipse:
1 with only the error-stream of my process
and 1 with only the std-stream of my process

I searched for an option or plugin to do this but couldn't find any.
It should be failry easy to implement in Eclipse for so. who is familiar with the Eclipse PDE.

Any ideas how to do this or is anybody willing to build this plugin?